# Using Linux Mint as a Windows application

Tags: linux-mint

I know it is possible to install Ubuntu as a Windows application. I'd like to know if it is also possible to do so with Linux Mint, which I would like to try.

I already know that this kind of usage will have bad performance, but since I just need the Linux dist to run one single program I still want to do this.

Would it be better to install into a VirtualBox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, Wubi (which you probably mean by installing Ubuntu "as a Windows application") doesn't actually install Linux as an application; rather, it installs Linux in a disk image that lives within Windows' partition.

You could go with a virtual machine with a lightweight distro (like Xubuntu), which should provide good performance in any recent machine.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off to install VirtualBox (or VMWare Player, etc.) - the performance would be better plus Mint is actually relatively lightweight; I used that under VMWare Fusion 4 rather than Ubuntu because of better support for environments that couldn't support the Unity interface (Like VMWare Fusion 4).